# Unable to add a component in Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

The Below picture shows that when I add component it always shows "Incomplete".

I am using visual studio 2015. Please give a solution for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **Nuget Package** of Appcompat library.

1. Right Click on **References**
2. **Manage NuGet Packages**
3. Search for **Xamarin.Android.Support.V7.AppCompat**
4. Install **Xamarin.Android.Support.V7.AppCompat**